# Checking a Calculator display has one number in the innerHTML string

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a calculator with vanilla JavaScript. I'm trying to make an if statement to find out whether the current result displayed has only one number left in the string. If this is true I want to make sure when the user clicks the delete button the current display returns to the default display instead of having no numbers in the string. I hope I explained this properly. How would I go about making this check.

```
const deleteNumber = () => {
    let newDisplayedResult = currentResult[0].innerHTML.slice(0, -1);

    if (firstNumber !== "" && currentOperator !== "") {
        secondNumber = newDisplayedResult;
        currentResult[0].innerHTML = newDisplayedResult;
    } else {
        firstNumber = newDisplayedResult;
        currentResult[0].innerHTML = newDisplayedResult;
    }
};
```

Comment: Please, [edit] to create a [mcve].

Comment: PS... why don't you use `*` or `×` for multiplication?

Comment: I do the calculation works fine its the delete button that is the problem.

Comment: How would I check if there is only one number in the string ?

Comment: Create a [mcve].

Comment: you mean the length of string is 1 and it is digit?

Comment: yes. When there is only one number left in the string. I want to make the result show the default one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let re = new RegExp('^[0-9]$');
re.test(str)
```

or:

```
str.length === 1 && "0123456789".split("").includes(str)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help I completed my project and learned something new :)